# Whats wrong with this jquery ajax post?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I'm trying to post some form data and return results but I am having trouble getting this to work:

The javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#sendthis").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#theform').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                url: "form.php",
                success: function (data) {

                    alert(data);

                }
            });

            return false;

        });

    });
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<form id="theform">
    <input type="text" class="sized" name="name" id="name"><br />
    <input type="text" class="sized" name="email" id="email">
</form>

<a href="#" id="sendthis">Submit</a>
```

The page to post to (form.php):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])){
    $result = $_POST['name'];
}

echo $result;
?>
```

Now, it is my understanding that when the form is submitted, it would post to form.php, and the input value of "name" would be returned in an alert box. However, I can't seem to get the form data posting (or maybe returning) correctly.

Is it a problem with `$('#theform').serialize()`? Maybe something else?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Stop guessing - take firebug and fix it

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` and see what's coming through. Adding debug output is easy and a quick way to start figuring out what's wrong, rather than flailing around in the dark. And enough things can go wrong at the HTTP level to not have an error handler in the ajax code, so add an error: section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it works

```
<form id="theform" action="/form.php">
    <input type="text" class="sized" name="name" id="name"/><br />
    <input type="text" class="sized" name="email" id="email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The jquery

```
$("#theform").on('submit', function () {
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    return false;   
});
```

Comment: Only hidden form fields (those with predefined values) are being posted. All other form fields such as text inputs are not being posted even when a value is inserted.

Comment: I don't see any hidden form fields in the example you provided so perhaps you would get a better answer if you posted a better representation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: There's no point in adding an action or a submit button, since the OP is handling that himself in his ajax code. All you've done is a teensy bit of "graceful degradation" enhancement, which is not the point of the question.

Comment: @MarcB, if you notice, I also added a '/' in front of form.php since without it, it's relative to the current directory. I just slightly optimized while I was at it. There is a method to my madness. lol.

Comment: @rob: adding a slash would be pointless if this was in example.com/subdir/subdir/test.php... now you're probably causing a 404.

Comment: @MarcB, no point in arguing. I was just trying to help troubleshoot it and would revise the answer based on new info (hence 'try this and see if it works') since we don't know if that's intentional or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an error callback to your ajax request to catch if there are issues being encountered during the post.  Do you have a debugger like firebug that can show you what data is being posted (and where)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just used firebug and noticed that ONLY the hidden form fields are being posted and not the normal input fields...? Can't figure out why. (The pages obviously have more content than the above pasted code)

Comment: Can you post your code or a replicable example of the serialize logic not working in a jsFiddle?  Without seeing the issue replicated it's tough to guess.  Might be some formatting error or invalid html (for example, your input tags above aren't closed).

Comment: John, not showing everything in the form makes this very confusing. The only fields you've shown us are name and email. +1 to Jim, as he is right. The answer on this one is to use your NET tab in your debugger to watch the requests, then edit your question with more detail when you have more information about what is happening under the hood. Good luck!

Comment: I've found that only the hidden form fields are posting (ie. a field with a specified VALUE). Nothing without a predefined value is posting. What would cause this?